# Visualforce Input Picklist from Child Object

Tags: picklist, dependent-picklist

I have a visualforce page to generate a OpportunityLineItem.
It is launched from the Opportunity page.
I want a picklist for users to enter a custom field Product_Type__c.

The Opportunity is the controller of record on the page.

I can make this list manually in code, but how do I query to get the custom field values Product_Type__c as a picklist on the page?

How do I assign this to a value and how do I restrict values? Example:

```
//manual list option    
       public List<SelectOption> getEmailTypes() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        options.add(new SelectOption('Intro','Intro'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Promotional','Promotional'));
        return options;
    }
```

Comment: Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Opportunity.Product_Type__c.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();  use the above list in select option

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps this is answer? Also, how do I assign this in the record creation?

Comment: I have split out part of this to another question

Comment: Do you need to display the picklist in visualforce page??